# Read oracle tables using .NET, one LONG type column always returns empty string, how to solve it?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am reading from a table all_tab_columns, there is a "data_default" column, which is a type of LONG.

If I query the oracle server using sqlplus, such as "select data_default from all_tab_columns where table_name='testtable'", everything is fine. The correct default value for each columns of the table "testtable" can be returned.

But if I use the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll (well, I am using Spartacus library, which in turn uses Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll), for the same query, the data_default column always returns empty string '', I tried several other columns such as column_name, table_name, owner etc. they are all fine.

My question is how do I debug such case? I couldn't locate the root cause of this peculiar error. Any suggestion will be welcome.

Thanks.

---

The source code for spartacus to read from oracle is as follows,

```
this.v_con = new OracleManaged.OracleConnection(this.v_connectionstring);
this.v_con.Open();
this.v_cmd = new OracleManaged.OracleCommand(p_sql, this.v_con);
if (this.v_timeout > -1)
    this.v_cmd.CommandTimeout = this.v_timeout;
this.v_reader = this.v_cmd.ExecuteReader();

v_table = new System.Data.DataTable(p_tablename);
for (int i = 0; i < this.v_reader.FieldCount; i++)
    v_table.Columns.Add(this.v_reader.GetName(i), typeof(string));

while (this.v_reader.Read())
{
    v_row = v_table.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.v_reader.FieldCount; i++)
        v_row[i] = this.v_reader[i].ToString();
    v_table.Rows.Add(v_row);
}
```

I tried to debug, the v_reader[i].ToString() for data_default column is empty already. Seems there's no way for me to solve it? Is it probably the .dll problem?

Comment: Hi, source code attached. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> #### Obtaining LONG and LONG RAW Data
>
> ODP.NET fetches and caches rows from the database during the Read method invocations on the OracleDataReader object. The amount of LONG and LONG RAW column data that is retrieved from this operation is determined by InitialLONGFetchSize. [More](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featData.htm#i1007197)

You may need to set the `InitialLONGFetchSize` to a non-zero value and use the OracleDataReader's `GetOracleString()` method, and use `ToString()` to convert the result into a `.Net` string.

Comment: Thanks. Added this.v_cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1024; after the creation of this.v_cmd solves the problem.

Comment: Hi, @user534498 and @JSapkota, I'm Spartacus' creator and maintainer. I wasn't aware of `InitialLONGFetchSize` attribute, and I'm going to include this workaround in next Spartacus release. Thanks!

Comment: @wind39 Thanks for the great work. I now face another problem for oracle, with the query “select count(*) as total from table1 union all select count(*) as total from table2", the oracle returns 0, and 0 (mysql returns correct value). While in sqlplus console, the correct value is returned. Do you think I should probably open another question?

Comment: @user534498 Oracle is returning two rows with the value 0? Both table1 and table2 are empty? `union all` is working as expected, it doesn't eliminates replications on result. Can you please provide more details?

Comment: @wind39 nvm, It's my fault this time. I used sqlplus to insert several data in table and test using Spartacus client but failed to read data out. As soon as I quit sqlplus, everything works. It seems that sqlplus will cache the small amount of data until you logout.

Comment: @user534498 Glad to hear :) I think on logout, sqlplus commits alterations. You can try `commit;` inside sqlplus after inserting data.